# `bufio.Writer` or `io.Writer`?

Tags: go, interface

I have a function that writes data to anything that implements an interface with a `Write(b []byte) (n int, err error)` method. Right now in my program I write to an actual `Conn`, but following best practices (https://dave.cheney.net/2016/08/20/solid-go-design) and because I only call `Write`, I want to accept the minimum interface that implements that method. For that, I accept a parameter with interface `io.Writer`.

Since my function could be outputting lots of data very fast, should I be accepting a `bufio.Writer` instead? Or is it in the function’s consumer responsibility to use a buffered writer instead of a plain one? What are best practices?

Comment: That's entirely up to you. `io.Writer` makes it more flexible, and the caller should know whether buffered io is necessary or not. (plus, what about sufficiently buffered writers that aren't a `bufio.Writer`?)

Comment: "Since my function could be outputting lots of data very fast" - irrelevant. Just take an `io.Writer`, and if *your function* needs the additional functionality exposed by `bufio.Writer`, then wrap the one you get yourself (maybe type-assert first to see if it's already a `bufio.Writer`).

Comment: Also, buffered output does not inherently make "lots of data very fast" faster. It allows one to batch relatively expensive syscalls for efficient streaming, but that of course comes with some overhead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create your function to accept `io.Writer`, and **document** that it will write a lot of data, and so `bufio.Writer` or a similar construct is *advised*.

Do not limit users of your function to `bufio.Writer`, as you only use the functionality of an `io.Writer`. Also users may have other "buffered" implementation of `io.Writer` that will be sufficient for them.

Don't decide what's good for the users of your library, let them decide what's good for them. Should the users find `bufio.Writer` useful or better than their `io.Writer` implementation, they can always wrap it in a `bufio.Writer` and pass that (simply using `bufio.NewWriter(w)`).

If you create your function to accept `io.Writer`, users can always add the wrapping functionality very easily with a one-line utility function:

```
func wrapAndPass(w io.Writer) {
    yourFunction(bufio.NewWriter(w))
}
```

If you create your function to accept `bufio.Writer`, then there is no way for the users to undo this "wrapping". Users will be forced to always create and pass a `bufio.Writer`, whether it's needed or not.

Also you may opt to provide *two* functions: your original function taking `io.Writer`, and the above wrapping-and-passing utility function. If you do so, it would also be nice to check if the passed writer is already a `*bufio.Writer`, in which case wrapping should be avoided. Something like this:

```
func wrapIfNeededAndPass(w io.Writer) {
    if _, ok := w.(*bufio.Writer); !ok {
        w = bufio.NewWriter(w)
    }
    yourFunction(w)
}
```

But usually this kind of wrapping is only applied if extra functionality is needed "beyond" `io.Writer`.