# How can I write go profile to file as it goes?

Tags: go, pprof

I am trying to profile a go application and below is the code:

```golang
func main() {
    defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    f, err := os.Create("./profile.tar.gz")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
    ...
```

I am able to see the file was created on the disk once the application exits. Is there a way to flush the profile to disk without quitting the application? My application is a rest API which will keep running for a long time. I'd like to see profile file during the run time. I may create an internal rest `path` in the application to flush profile data into file.

Comment: I think you can use the [net/http/pprof](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof) package to serve the profile without writing the profile to disk.

Comment: Implement the writer interface and flush the contents of whatever you are trying to write to the file itself as the programs fill the buffer (this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48115577/bufio-writer-or-io-writer)

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the code of `pprof.NewCPUProfile` it doesn't seem to be able to do that. It only writes (and stops profiling) to whatever writer you have passed if it receives an EOF signal when trying to do an internal [`readProfile`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go;l=810). The function that actually writes data into the file is called [`build`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/runtime/pprof/proto.go;l=348) and it is only called three times in the package and one of the times it's from the [`profileWriter`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.5:src/runtime/pprof/pprof.go;l=805) (a goroutine spawned by pprof's `NewCPUProfile` function.

I'd use the [net/http/pprof](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/pprof) package and from them export whatever profile file you want.